# how to sum two complex numbers in eulers form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was wondering if there was a fast track method of summing two complex numbers in eulers form. I have scoured the internet and have yet to find a method that can be considered simple.

I was trying to solve this for $z = e^{\frac{i3\pi}{4}}$ for the limit of $z$ to $e^{\frac{i3\pi}{4}}$

$$lim \frac{1}{(z - e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})(z + e^{\frac{i3\pi}{4}})(z+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})(z^2 + 1)^2}$$

that being said i was thinking of using hopital's rule for limits but I was wondering how i would have to solve $e^{\frac{i3\pi}{4}} - e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$ in an effective manner that wouldn't have to force me to use sinus and cosine functions.

essentially i was wondering if there's a method to solve this without using a calculator.

Comment: $e^{i\alpha} - e^{i \beta} = 2 i e^{i (\alpha + \beta)/2} \sin (\alpha - \beta)/2$

Comment: In general you will need to use trigonometry to add vectors/complex numbers in polar form. This particular problem shouldn't need a calculator (or numerical approximation) because these are common angles on the unit circle. For example, $z = e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1+i)$. You are able to convert all of these terms into Cartesian form exactly, so no need for a calculator.